# nth-child targets only children

Tags: css

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li>111
        <ul id="sub-menu">
            <li>sub-111</li>
            <li>sub-222</li>
            <li>sub-333</li>
            <li>sub-444</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>222</li>
    <li>333</li>
    <li>444</li>
</ul>


<style>
    ul#main-menu li:nth-child(2n) {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

this is a demo 
http://cssdeck.com/labs/emxvbal4

This effects the sub items also !!

How can I target only the li's of the main-menu without touching the li's of the sub-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors) (`>`) instead of the [descendant one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors) ():

```css
ul#main-menu > li:nth-child(2n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use direct children selector:

```
#main-menu > li{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use immediate children selector ">".

```
ul#main-menu > li {
    <your_css_style>
}
```

For more info., check this [LINK](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).